# settings_location.php - is there an example

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, kcfinder

I'm trying to browse images in wysiwyg editor (via the kcfinder) (for example Event description) but I get an error due to misconf.
I hits the file civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php which loads civicrm/settings_location.php (which you have to create) but I'm missing something inside this file, Is there an example of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `settings_location.php` file should not normally be required, but an example is described at:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=83034188

The file `civicrm.config.php` should be able to handle bootstrap in most common configurations without `settings_location.php`. However, this depends on having somewhat plain/predictable directory structure, and it could break down when using things like (a) symlinks, (b) special filesystems, or (c) multi-tenant/multi-site installations.

Comment: It is only required when I try to browse images with wysiwyg editor. i.e. /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/browse.php?cms=civicrm&type=images&CKEditor=ten_how_to_get_there&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=en-gb

It may be because I use WP Const & functions in my civicrm.settings.php which are not avail at that point. I have checked the templates/CRM/common/civicrm.settings.php.template and it uses macros i.e. %%dbUser%%. How do i set these macros?

Comment: The macros which appear in the `civicrm.settings.php.template` are generally applied during installation. (For civicrm-wordpress, you may recall an install screen that asks for DB credentials.) The alternative is to do it manually (e.g. `cp wp-content/plugins/templates/CRM/common/civicrm.settings.php.template wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php` and then search/edit anything with `%%`), although that would override any customizations in that file.